# OrderBy based on column value in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

As of now my Query is working fine,

But I need to add another specific field called `reseller_type`

Reseller type has 3 different types

```
VALUE    |    DEFINITION
0        =       NONE
1        =       Resale
2        =       Resale : Show to first
3        =       Resale : Show to last
```

If the value of reseller type is 0 means, NONE

If the value of reseller type is 1 means, record is `just simple resale`

If the value of reseller type is 2 means, record is `resale but need to show first`

If the value of reseller type is 3 means, record is `resale but need to show to last`

Now in my query I'm trying to show if the reseller type of the record has value of 2 then it will show first before the other records, but if the value is 3 it will automatically show in the last only.

This is my query code.

```
          $base_query = DB::table('yeast_module')
            ->select('yeast_module.id','yeast_module.part_number','yeast_module.part_name','yeast_module.category',
            'yeast_module.description','yeast_module.spec_sheet','yeast_module.yeast_category',
            'yeast_module.optimum_fermentation_temp_f_low',
            'yeast_module.optimum_fermentation_temp_f_high',
            'yeast_module.optimum_fermentation_temp_c_low',
            'yeast_module.optimum_fermentation_temp_c_high',
            'yeast_module.alcohol_tolerance','yeast_module.packaging',

            'yeast_module.organic',
            'yeast_module.reseller_type',
            'yeast_module.flocculation',
            'yeast_module.attenuation_low_end',
            'yeast_module.attenuation_high_end',
            'yeast_module.sta1qc',
            'yeast_module.style_recommendation',
            'yeast_module.beer_style',
            'yeast_module.search_tags',


            'yeast_module.photo','yeast_module.deleted','yeast_module.created_at','yeast_module.updated_at',
            'yeast_category.category_desc')
            ->join('yeast_category','yeast_category.id','=','yeast_module.category')
            ->where(['yeast_module.deleted' => 0])
            ->where(['yeast_category.deleted' => 0])
            ->where(['yeast_module.category' => $id]);


          $data = $base_query->groupBy('yeast_module.id')->paginate(20);
          return $data;
```

Comment: where is the query for `reseller_type`?

Comment: Not yet composed, just trying to do it.

Answer (score 1):

One option is to sort based on a custom list. You can use `FIELD()` function to do that in MySQL. In laravel you can do something like this:

```
$base_query->orderByRaw('FIELD(reseller_type, 2,1,0,3)');
```